# Combine 2 count queries into 1

Tags: mysql

Unable to get total per accountcode, it gives me a sum of all, here is the code

```
SELECT cdr.accountcode,
(SELECT COUNT(id)  FROM cdr WHERE cdr.calldate > now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE and cdr.dstchannel LIKE '%neural%') AS callcount , 
(SELECT COUNT(id)  FROM cdr WHERE cdr.calldate > now() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE and cdr.dstchannel LIKE '%neotel%')  AS localcallcount
FROM cdr
```

Table Structure

```
id | calldate   | clid  | src | dst             | dstchannel | accountcode | note
---+------------+-------+-----+-----------------+------------+-------------+------
12 | 2018-12-05 | "105" | 105 | SIP/neotel/1234 | 1234user   | testuser    | null
```

Expected output

> accountcode callcount localcallcount
>
> 5000user      1        2
>   5236user      1        3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Table structure with data sample and expected output is welcome. Otherwise, we can't help you

Comment: share table structure and few rows as data sample

Comment: I need to GROUP BY cdr.accountcode

Comment: There is no `5000user` or `5236user` in your data sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`. `COUNT()` counts every line, no matter what. The boolean expression in the `SUM()` function returns either 1 or 0, depending on if it's true or false.

```
SELECT cdr.accountcode,
SUM(cdr.calldate > now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE and cdr.dstchannel LIKE '%neural%') AS callcount , 
SUM(cdr.calldate > now() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE and cdr.dstchannel LIKE '%neotel%')  AS localcallcount
FROM cdr
```

Comment: Then feel free to add that `GROUP BY` to the query. If there's something else wrong in the query, please provide sufficiently enough sample data and desired result.